# DRUPAL - Retrieve a user's name / first name when the page is viewed with Google Tag Manager

Tags: drupal, integration, google-tag-manager, tracking

for the moment in my contents I have statistics that go back (ID, Date, User) with the module Visitors when a content is seen. However my users have a name and surname. I would like to retrieve the ID, date, last name and first name when a content is seen with Google Tag Manager.
I did not find much information about this in my research. Can you help me?
I use Drupal 7.

Thank you

Comment: Sorry hello is not showing, so Hello :)

Answer (score 0):

If your website displays the user's information, such as "Welcome Canadian Deer" then you would we able to do this straight in GTM by using pulling a **Variable** based on an **DOM Element** such as ID or other CSS Selector.

If you don't have this information exposed in the DOM you will need push it in the DataLayer to GTM and then create a **Variable** to read the **DataLayer**. Here is a Drupal 7 plugin to assist with that: https://www.drupal.org/project/datalayer (I have not used this plugin myself before)